# How do I Invoke a procedure when inside another procedure in Pascal

Tags: delphi, pascal, procedure

```
procedure questiontype;  
 begin  
  writeln ('Enter the type of question you would like...');  
  writeln ('1. Add');  
  writeln ('2. Multiply');  
  writeln ('3. Subtraction');  
  writeln ('4. Division');  
  readln (typeofquestion);  
   case typeofquestion of
    1: add;
    2: multiply;
    3: subraction;
    4: division   
else writeln ('Choose again'); 
end;
end;
```

The add, multiply, subtraction and division are all procedures. If i put this in the main program, it will work fine, but when i make this as a procedure itself, i get the error *undeclared identifier*. I've looked on many websites for an example that is like this but i can't find any.

How do make add, multiply, subtraction, division go to their procedures from inside this one?

Comment: You don't **goto** a procedure, you **call** or **invoke** a procedure. The difference might seem superficial, but Delphi has a **goto** keyword that you don't want to use. You don't even want to learn about it just yet.

Comment: @Cosmin, @David: Is there no `case` statement in pure Pascal?

Comment: @Andreas Pascal has case statement identical to Delphi

Comment: @Cosmin goto is probably useful in Pascal considering it doesn't have exceptions

Comment: @Cosmin I have a feeling original Pascal doesn't have break or exit either which makes goto more compelling!! But I wouldn't go out on a limb on that assertion.

Comment: @David, @Andreas, what's "original Pascal", and do we care about it? I actually expect people saying they use "Pascal" to use something like GNU Pascal or FPC. Maybe even Delphi!

Comment: @Cosmin The historical perspective is often interesting when working out how any language got to where it is. But I guess the OP is using Delphi.

Comment: @David: ...in which case you should mention the `interface` section, after all...

Comment: @Andreas My guess is that this code exists entirely in implementation section of one unit.

Comment: @David: Yes, of course, maybe these procedures *should* be invisible from other units. But the OP might still need to learn about that section and its relation to this question.

Comment: @Andreas Why don't you add an answer to make your point?

Comment: @David: Feels like stealing your rep points.

Comment: @Andreas Nonsense, you've got something to say, go for your life.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to declare procedures before routines that call them. Although you haven't shown how the other routines are defined, I deduce that they are declared after the routine you have shown.

So you can simply re-order your code so that add, multiply, subtraction and division are defined before they procedure that calls them.

So this will work:

```
procedure add;
begin
  //do something;
end;

procedure questiontype;  
begin  
  add;  
end;
```

But this will not compile:

```
procedure questiontype;  
begin  
  add;  
end;

procedure add;
begin
  //do something;
end;
```

Pascal and its variants are compiled in a single pass and if the compiler does not know about a routine at the point at which it is mentioned, it cannot continue.

Pascal does support co-routines where A calls B and B calls A, by the use of a *forward declaration`. For example:

```
procedure B; forward;

procedure A;
begin
  B;
end;

procedure B;
begin
  A;
end;
```

Naturally this is an infinite loop as written which will terminate with a stack overflow (how appropriate!) but there are of course real examples where this is necessary.

However, forward declarations are rarely needed and should be avoided if possible since they increase complexity. Invariably a solution can be found by simply re-ordering your declarations.

As a final aside, the ordering constraint that declaration occurs before use is explicitly mentioned in Brian Kernighan famous article, [Why Pascal is Not My Favorite Programming Language](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/bwk-on-pascal.html).

Comment: @David, how many downvotes did you get in the latest few days? Significantly more then usual? To me it looks like an epidemic. I've got a total of 8 downvotes since I opened my SO account, 4 of them in the last 4 days. My numbers are statistically irrelevant, they're too small.

Comment: My guess is that the downvoter only read the first tag of the question, namely, `[delphi]`, and noted that you said nothing about the `interface` section. Or maybe the downvoter was merely in a bad mood. Still, you should never downvote without leaving a comment, IMO.

Comment: @Cosmin: A few weeks ago someone (apparently) downvoted every answer I had given the last week or so.

Comment: @Andreas, I downvote from time to time without leaving comments for two reasons: There are reprisals from offended users in form of more downvotes (It happened to me twice) and there are times where the question is in too bad form, with unattended clarification requests or such things that I feel commenting is a waste of time, but you can still contribute by downvoting to automatically delete this bad quality questions someday.

Comment: ISO 7185 does not have units. The later standard (10206) does have a module system, but its syntax is more Modula2 like, with iirc MODULE DEFINITION and IMPLEMENTATION as substitute resp. UNIT/INTERFACE/IMPLEMENTATION keywords. The UCSD model that TP derived from was afaik based on an early concept draft for 10206, but the syntax was later changed.

Comment: Careful with the term co-routines. That term usually means something different.

Answer (score 6):

I see you have tagged your question `[delphi]` as well as `[pascal]`, so I guess you are in fact writing Delphi code. Then you got a few more options, besides caring about the order of the procedures and the `forward` directive discussed by David.

Most often a `Delphi` project (GUI *or* console) is divided into "units". A typical unit looks like this:

```
unit MyUnit;

interface

const
  RANDOM_NUMBER = 17;

var
  PrintExtraNiceMessage: boolean;

procedure DoThis;
procedure DoThat;

implementation

const
  BUFFER_SIZE = 256;

procedure InitSomething;
begin
  // TODO: do some internal work...
end;

procedure DoThis;
begin
  // TODO: do something
end;

procedure DoThat;
begin
  // TODO: do something else
end;
```

You will notice that the unit is divided in two parts: the `interface` part, and the `implementation` part. The `interface` part contains only declarations (of functions, procedures, types, constants, and variables); the functions and procedures declared here are defined (that is, implemented) in the `implementation` section. Notice that there can be functions and procedures defined in the `implementation` section that have no declarations in the `interface` section.

The grand idea is that the contents of the `interface` section is visible to all other units in your program, whereas the contents of the `implementation` section is only visible inside this very unit. So any other unit in your program can use the `RANDOM_NUMBER` constant, the `PrintExtraNiceMessage` variable and the two procedures `DoThis` and `DoThat`. But you can only use `InitFunction` in this very unit (for instance, *inside* `DoThis` or `DoThat`). In addition, the constant `BUFFER_SIZE` is not visible outside this very unit, either.

This is a very elegant approach. The `interface` section describes how this unit is used in other units (e.g., what functions there are and how they are used), and the implementation details are "hidden" in the `implementation` section.

A benefit of this approach is that it solves your problem, at least possibly. *If* the `add`, `multiply`, `subtract`, and `divide` procedures should be visible to other units, then they should be declared in the `interface` section. But then they are indeed known to the compiler by the time it comes to your `questiontype` procedure, and so you can use call these even if they are defined (implemented) below the `questiontype` procedure inside the `implementation` section. But, on the other hand, if it makes no sense at all to let other units use these procedures, then they should not be declared in the `interface` section, and you need to do as David suggests. This also applies if you have no normal units at all in your project, that is, if you only have the `program` file, which has no division into `interface` and `implementation` parts.

Comment: Minor point, I did not advocate that OP solves problem with `forward`.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the OP's example has an else that only applies to the last "if".  Presumably, if they enter 1, 2, or 3, the corresponding procedure fires, returns, and then they see 'Choose again'. If they enter 4, they do not. This would be well served by a Case or cascading if..else if structure where the final else is only triggered "when all else fails", which is like what the OP intended.

Comment: Yes, this is a bug in he OP's code. He should *really* use a `case` statement here (or learn more about how `if` and `else` works).

Comment: Please illustrate both approaches in your answer.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I've put a case statement in now and it works fine. Thanks.