# How to call a procedure from inside another procedure

Tags: freepascal, procedures

There is this link [How do I Invoke a procedure when inside another procedure in Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363287/how-do-i-invoke-a-procedure-when-inside-another-procedure-in-pascal) But its not exactly my case.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
   [...]
begin
  // click on button
  [...]
end;
```

and I have this procedure

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // on double click in flags
  [the same code like above]
end;
```

i tryed this but it does not work

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TForm1.Button1Click;
end;
```

then I tryed this

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
end;
```

it also does not work
Can somebody please help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call it directly, using either `nil` or another component as the `Sender`:

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1Click(nil);
end;  

procedure TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1Click(CheckListBox2);
end;
```

Note you don't use the classname (or variable name) of the form itself, since you're calling from the current instance of the form. IOW, do **not** use `TForm1` or `Form1` inside of a class method; that limits you to a specific instance of the form instead of being available to all instances. If you need to qualify it, use `Self`, as in `Self.Button1Click(nil);`.

Comment: Thank you, It works, in 7 minutes I accept it. but what is nil?

Comment: `nil` is an unassigned pointer. It means "pass a pointer to nothing to the procedure, because it requires a parameter". You can test it to see if it's nil using `if Sender <> nil` or `if not Assigned(Sender)`. `Sender` is the control that is "sending" the event (causing it to be invoked); since you're doing it from another control's event handler, it may or may not be appropriate to provide a `Sender` to the event you're manually firing, based on what your code is actually doing. As I don't have that information, I demonstrated both ways.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
procedure TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
TForm1.Button1Click(Sender);
end;
```

Comment: I get this ERROR : procmaileditor1.pas(145,30) Error: Only class class methods, class properties and class variables can be accessed in class methods

Comment: the second version is also not compiling : procmaileditor1.pas(146,30) Error: Only class class methods, class properties and class variables can be accessed in class methods

Comment: You may try to assign the function directly TForm1.CheckListBox2DblClick:=@TForm1.Button1Click